# building ROS on arch linux

Tags: ros, archlinux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings! I'm trying to build ros on arch linux. I followed this instruction
ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Arch
with some trouble along:

1)

```
 patch -p0 < ros.patch
```

`patching file simulator_gazebo/gazebo/Makefile.gazebo.tarball
Hunk #1 FAILED at 31.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file
simulator_gazebo/gazebo/Makefile.gazebo.tarball.rej
patching file geometry/tf/include/tf/message_filter.h
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.`

This error was repeated for all entries in the patch file.

2)
At the final step of

```
rosmake -a
```

the making started, but so far I encountered following errors:

`[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/camera_calibration_parsers.dir/src/parse_yml.o
  /home/aash29/ros/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:3:27: fatal error: yaml-cpp/yaml.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.`

And in another package

`` [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cv_bridge.dir/src/cv_bridge.o
  /home/aash29/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp: In function ‘std::map, std::vector > cv_bridge::getConversionCodes()’:
/home/aash29/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:179:47: error: ‘CV_YUV2GRAY_UYVY’ was not declared in this scope
/home/aash29/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:180:46: error: ‘CV_YUV2RGB_UYVY’ was not declared in this scope
/home/aash29/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:181:46: error: ‘CV_YUV2BGR_UYVY’ was not declared in this scope
/home/aash29/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:182:47: error: ‘CV_YUV2RGBA_UYVY’ was not declared in this scope
/home/aash29/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:183:47: error: ‘CV_YUV2BGRA_UYVY’ was not declared in this scope
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/cv_bridge.dir/src/cv_bridge.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/aash29/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cv_bridge.dir/all] Error 2 ``

What could cause it? Is it any easier to build previous versions of ros?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48800/building-ros-on-arch-linux/) by [aash29](https://answers.ros.org/users/3641/aash29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-11-21

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aash29](https://answers.ros.org/users/3641/aash29/) on 2012-11-22**:
thanks Lorenz, I didn't want to install a different distribution for the purpose of running a single package, but building under arch is beginning to appear infeasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Building ROS on Arch is definitely not trivial and the install instructions are probably outdated. The patches you were trying to apply are 8 months old.

I didn't build more than the ROS underlay recently in Arch and there are basically mainly three things you have to do:

1. Get the script to fix the python shebang lines from [here](https://raw.github.com/moesenle/arch-ros-stacks/master/ros-build-tools/fix-python-scripts.sh) and run it on your underlay.
2. Get rid of rx. I couldn't manage to compile it at the moment because of some weird swig error I don't have time to investigate right now.
3. Use the following cmake call: `cmake .. -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python2 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/fuerte`.
4. Open ros_comm/tools/rosbag/src/recorder.cpp and go to line 439. Change `boost::TIME_UTC` to `boost::TIME_UTC_` to make it compile with the most recent boost version.

This should allow you to build at least the middleware and the basic build system and command line tools. For higher-level stacks, you will have to fix a lot of code yourself which is a pretty time consuming process.

An alternative solution in case you need to stick with Arch and cannot switch to Ubuntu is to install a Ubuntu chroot environment in which you can install ROS using apt-get. Just google for debootstrap in case you want to try that.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if anyone (like me) found this question looking for the answer to this error:

CV_YUV2GRAY_UYVY’ was not declared in this scope

You will need to install opencv from source, the prebuilt binary is too old

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeremy Corbett](https://answers.ros.org/users/2912/jeremy-corbett/) on 2013-12-01**:
Thanks for the tip!
I'm battling away with getting hydro on a raspberry pi with opencv. It's a struggle, but pretty fun so far!. Next up Moveit!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you plan on moving to Groovy (resp. Hydro), there are [several AUR packages](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?K=ros-) for that. It's a work in progress, but you can have your setup with rviz installed quite easily now. You just need to follow the method presented in the [ROS Groovy wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Arch#Method_1:_Using_the_AUR_Packages) (resp. [ROS Hydro wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Arch#Method_1:_Using_the_AUR_Packages)):

```
yaourt --noconfirm ros-groovy
or
yaourt --noconfirm ros-hydro
```

(or the equivalent command for your AUR package manager)

The PKGBUILD scripts used can be found on [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/zootboy/arch-ros-stacks).

---

Originally posted by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) with karma: 596 on 2013-10-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aash29](https://answers.ros.org/users/3641/aash29/) on 2013-10-31**:
ok, thanks! Since then I installed ubuntu for sole reason of running ROS

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2013-11-04**:
I used to run ROS in a Virtualbox Ubuntu VM, but I went back to Arch Linux recently. The only problem I have for the moment is with PCL and stacks that depend on it, but it should be fixed soon enough.

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2014-01-22**:
FYI, Hydro can also be installed with AUR packages. It works quite well so far ;-)

**Comment by [aash29](https://answers.ros.org/users/3641/aash29/) on 2014-01-22**:
Good news, thanks!